EntitiyManager constructor injection
I have a service that uses both spring jpa and manually managed transactions. I would like to inject an EntityManager by constructor and not @PersistenceContext.
@Service
public class MyService {

  private final EntityManager entityManager;
  private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
  
  public MyService(final EntityManager entityManager,
                             final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.transactionTemplate = transactionTemplate;
  

}
}
How is the correct way to do it? I found the post https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15076. Now i'm uncertain. Does spring jpa provide a shared entity manager or do i have to create a bean like that?
@Bean
public EntityManager sharedEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(emf);
}

